Solving minimum 2-norm least squares problem with a metric
I am trying to solve a standard least-squares problem of the form:
$x = \text{argmin}|Ax-b|^2$,
where $A$ has a non-trivial null space. I want the minimum 2-norm solution with the norm $\|x\|^2 = x^T M x$ for some positive definite $M$ (not necessarily diagonal, but sparse and can be huge). For $M = Id$, it's just a pseudo-inverse solution of the form $x = A^{\dagger}b$. However, I struggle with the generalization to any PD $M$. The possibilities I have are:

Cholesky $M$ into $M = LL^T$, set $y = Lx$, and solve for $y = \text{argmin}|AL^{-T}y-b|^2$. The problem is I don't see how I can easily (computationally) get $L^{-T}$. This might work if the pseudo-inverse of $AL^{-T}$ somehow cancels out terms, but it's not obvious that it does (maybe?).

Set it as a saddle-point Lagrange multiplier problem of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}M &  A^TA\\ A^TA & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ \lambda\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ A^T b\end{pmatrix}
$$
This is disadvantageous for several reasons: a) the problem is twice as large, b) a PSD problem that can be solved with LDLT becomes a symmetric problem that can only be solved by LU. c) even if using Schur's complement to reduce it, you get a nasty expression with 4 times A multiplied against itself, which numerically worsens its condition number.


It seems like the problem becomes much more difficult for a relatively minor change that does not change the convexity of the problem. What is the best course of action?

The norm to minimize the residual is also induced by $M$? Or the $M$-norm is supposed to minimize the norm of $x$ but the residual minimizing norm is different?

Yeah different norms. A is not square.

That's true, of course.

Just for fun, let's introduce another SPD matrix $N$ and consider a problem of finding the $x$ which minimizes the residual norm $\|b-Ax\|_N$ and has the smallest $M$-norm.
Let $R_M$ and $R_N$ be matrices such that $M=R_M^TR_M$ and $N=R_N^TR_N$, not necessarily triangular but can be upper triangular factors of their matrices computed using the Cholesky factorization. Then $\|b-Ax\|_N=\|R_Nb-R_NAx\|_2$ and $\|x\|_M=\|R_Mx\|_2$.
We convert this problem to a minimum-norm least squares problem in terms of the 2-norm, for which we know the solution lies in the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of the matrix.
It is actually quite straightforward how to proceed. Let us introduce a vector $y=R_Mx$. Then $\|x\|_M=\|y\|_2$ and $\|b-Ax\|_N=\|R_Nb-R_NAR_M^{-1}y\|_2$.
So the minimum $M$-norm solution to minimizing the $N$-norm of the residual is given by
$$
y=(R_NAR_M^{-1})^\dagger R_Nb \quad \implies \quad x=R_M^{-1}(R_NAR_M^{-1})^\dagger R_Nb.
$$
A direct way to tackle the computation of the pseudo-inverse would be to form the matrix $R_NAR_M^{-1}$ explicitly (though without forming the explicit inverse of $R_M^{-1}$ but instead using triangular solves with $R_M$!!!), then using, e.g., SVD on the resulting matrix. I suspect an approach based on weighted SVD might be possible but I'm not that familiar with it, unfortunately.

Right. So it's similar to my solution (1). However, is it possible that since M is PD that you can take it out of the pseudoinverse? Then you don't need to invert at all.

@AmirVaxman Unfortunatelly it does not work that way. It might be if $A$ was full rank but without this assumption I doubt it would work.
